# How does Single-logout works with OKTA(IDP)-Shibboleth(SP)-App

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp, single-logout

OKTA-Shibboleth(Apache)-Nakisa(Tomcat)

SSO is working for logging-in. 
Now, I need to configure Logout. So, user logs out from the app, user needs to be redirected to OKTA page with tiles.

But, currently,user is redirected to the app again.

It's sending user to /logout?redirect=default.html but that default.html is captured by Apache rule and logging user back in.

It looks like it needs to hit 
https://xxxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout. When I access this url, it says logout is successfully done although it's not going back to OKTA.  Does that mean that in the App's logout setting, they need to redirect to this?

But, how do I make user to go back to IdP(i.e OKTA) again?

This is what I assume that will happen.

```
Logout button click > logout from Shibboleth > return to OKTA so user can click other tiles.
```

Something to configure Shibboleth2.xml? 
Document says i just need to configure the following which is there by default.

```
<!-- SAML and local-only logout. -->
        <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
```

But, how does it redirect user to OKTA(IdP) once user log out completes. 
Is it configured in IdP's metadata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the user after a local logout event anywhere you'd like, via passing the `?return=` parameter a URL-encoded destination, i.e. you should update your logout link to:

```
https://xxxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

in order to redirect folks to Google once logout has taken place.

Now, you only need an Okta URL to return folks to... so I think if your client's Okta tenant is "foobar.okta.com", redirecting them after local logout to the Okta login page *shouldn't* prompt them to login, since they will already have the Okta Session... so maybe try:

```
https://xxxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https%3A%2F%2Ffoobar.okta.com%2Flogin
```

Of course, you'll need to test that... but it should work, and on the off chance that the user's Shibboleth SP session was active, and their Okta session invalidated through some other mechanism, that'll just return them to their regular Okta login page.

You can obviously redirect them to any endpoint with the `return` parameter, for example, whatever Okta's logout URL (if you wanted to kill their Okta session too).

The only logout that's configurable by Metadata is SLO (single logout), i.e. if you wanted it to, Shibboleth can redirect the user to Okta after they complete the logout of the SP session, along with a specially-craft `<LogoutRequest>` assertion payload, which Okta would parse and act on in any number of ways, i.e. killing the user's Okta session, propagating Okta-initiated subsequent `<LogoutRequest>` assertions to other Service Providers, etc. In practice, this never really works, because such configurations are very difficult to get working between all of the relevant parties.

Comment: https://xxxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https%3A%2F%2Ffoobar.okta.com%2Flogin just works. hmm. it logs me out and redirect to Okta page. I see SAML is again request/respond after I click the app button. The question is that do I really need set single logout setting in OKTA still described here https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D50Z00008G7VXv/single-logout  ?  looks like that's not used at all.

Comment: I expected a request similar to this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218298/how-to-implement-single-logout-using-okta-as-idp  but, why do I need this if I can just logout with /Logout and redirect to OKTA with return param ? Is that for a different purpose?

Comment: by reading your answer , I see you suggested two methods. 1) local logout then redirect  2) single logout - LogoutRequest . It looks like 1st approach just works and there is no reason to use 2nd approach unless I want to. Is this corrrect?

Comment: Oh. since it starts from the app's logout, it's requesting from the app with redirect already.  something like this: https://xxx/leasing/app/logout?redirect=https://xxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://xxx.oktapreview.com/app/UserHome.  The 2nd 'return=' is not recognized. Should I capture it from Apache and redirect from there?

Comment: I wouldn't try doing SLO... for one thing, I don't think Okta truly supports SLO. I would just call xxx/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=(okta url). You don't really want to kill the Okta session, and returning the user to the Okta portal can be achieved by setting the return to the Okta generic login url (not your Okta-initated app login url, a generic one). Since the user will still have an Okta session they should be pushed to the Okta portal.

Comment: Have you seen something like this? Okta click -> SSO ->then signin most of the time. But, once in a while, I landed on App's login page. When I try again, it logs me in. timing issue?

Comment: Wouldn't know without logs... Are you able to use [SAMLTracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) (or [SAML DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-devtools-extension/jndllhgbinhiiddokbeoeepbppdnhhio?hl=en-US) on Chrome) to watch the SAML workflow happen?

Comment: It is so intermittent, so not easy to capture that moment. can I log SAML response to a file for a few hours? hehe..

Comment: Yeah... you can. Just edit /etc/shibboleth/shibd.logger to enable debug logging for OpenSAML (the properties are `log4j.category.OpenSAML.MessageDecoder=DEBUG` and
`log4j.category.OpenSAML.MessageEncoder=DEBUG`). That should log the SAML to /var/log/shibd.log. You should probably also have the root debugger set to DEBUG.